# ¿Por qué "carabina" es "Mujer de edad que acompañaba a ciertas señoritas, especialmente cuando eran cortejadas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado

La acepción de **carabina** como algo diferente a "arma de fuego" no aparece en el DRAE hasta 1936 donde figura como "fig. y fam. Señorita de compañia".

¿Cuál es el origen de esa acepción?

Comment: Pensaba que sería un préstamo de otro idioma, pero no: al menos en francés y en italiano la palabra "carabina" solo tiene la acepción del arma de fuego, así que ha sido algo propio del español...

Comment: Aunque en México el término empleado para tal acompañante, desde tiempos de la colonia, es *chaperon* claramente palabra prestada del francés con el mismo significado. Por otro lado esto le da un nuevo contexto y significado a un antiguo programa cómico que solía transmitirse en horario solo apto  para​ adultos en los 70s y 80s: "*La carabina de Ambrosio*". Siempre me pregunté por qué se llamaría así, y ahora todo tiene sentido, pues empleaba principalmente humor considerado inmoral o subido de tono en aquellos tiempos.

Comment: @hlecuanda en realidad "la carabina de Ambrosio" es una expresión usada para indicar que algo es inútil o no vale nada.

Comment: @Carlos Alejo Por esto me encanta este sitio: todos los días aprendo algo nuevo y sorprendente sobre mi lenguaje! Gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Se ve que en este caso tenemos un origen madrileño de la acepción. La primera vez que aparece este significado en un diccionario es en 1901, en el *Nuevo diccionario enciclopédico ilustrado de la lengua castellana*, de Miguel de Toro y Gómez:

> fam. Mujer que acompaña a una joven.

Más adelante, en 1917 aparece también en el *Diccionario de la lengua española*, de José Alemany y Bolufer:

> fig. y fam. En Madrid, mujer que sirve de acompañante a una joven.

Y a continuación, en 1936, el *Diccionario histórico de la lengua española* de la RAE dice así:

> fig. y fam. Señorita de compañía.

Y cita los siguientes ejemplos:

> "Las señoritas de Madrid que llevan ahora, cuando van de paseo, una acompañanta a quien llaman la *carabina*."
>
> J. Valera, "La buena fama", 1896.
>
> ---
>
> "Bien hacen algunas muchachas desenfadadas en llamar *carabina* a tales ayas o acompañantas."
>
> J. Valera, "De varios colores", 1898.

Por tanto, se ve que a finales del siglo XIX ya existía esta figura. También existía por aquel entonces en España el [Cuerpo de Carabineros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuerpo_de_Carabineros_(Espa%C3%B1a)), cuyo lema era *Moralidad, lealtad, valor y disciplina*. Se entendía por tanto a un carabinero (portador de una carabina) como aquella persona cuya misión era defender la moral. Del mismo modo, se comenzó a denominar *carabina* al instrumento (en este caso una mujer) encargado de defender la moral y la decencia de las mujeres jóvenes.

El motivo de que el diccionario de la RAE tardara tanto en recoger el término fue seguramente su ausencia en textos escritos, dado que durante un tiempo fue un término coloquial usado mayormente en la expresión oral en un ámbito muy localizado. Otros diccionarios que no tenían ese requisito de que las palabras tuvieran que aparecer escritas recogieron antes esta acepción.

Comment: +1. Esta respuesta es mucho mejor que la mía. Gran trabajo de documentación, como siempre.

Comment: Dicen en [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/carabina-o-chaperona.1723312/): _La carabina se lleva colgada del hombro a todas partes, y seguro que acaba siendo un incordio para el que la lleva, de ahí que a la tercera persona que las buenas maneras imponían a las parejas se llame así._ Por cierto, al parecer se le llama también [_chaperón_](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?chapero.n).

Answer (score 1):

Hay que aclarar que "Señorita de compañía" no sería del todo correcto y puede dar a confusión, ya que `carabina` no se aplica a mujeres que hacen compañía a hombres, si no a señoras de mayor edad que vigilaban a damas más jóvenes.

> **[Carabina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7NpYmIP)**
>
> 2. f. coloq. Mujer de edad que acompañaba a ciertas señoritas, especialmente cuando eran cortejadas.

De acuerdo a [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?carabina), la palabra es un préstamo del francés y se refiere por supuesto al arma de fuego, pero adquirió el sentido de "estar vigilante".

El arma aparentemente era usada por ciertos soldados de caballería que hacían tareas de guardia y escolta y se llamaban *carabin* (el arma era designada *carabine*). Por eso el femenino de la palabra designa tanto al arma como a la función de vigilancia o guardia. Posiblemente por eso el término fue adopatado para hacer referencia a aquellas señoras que "vigilaban o guardaban" a otras más jóvenes.

De ahí deriva también el término español *carabinero*.